# In VBA, Trying to search through array with input from a range

Tags: arrays, vba, search, range, matching

I am attempting to take 5 inputs from 5 cells in a column (all numbers) and see if they match an array I have set. Ideally I would like for an array value to be ignored once a match has been found. Once a match is found I just need to change a cell value to a 1 or 0 (I have this part down pat haha)

I've tried .Find and a few other things. Obviously the code here will not work

```
Sub Q1()
    Dim arr1(5) As Variant
        arr1(0) = 100
        arr1(1) = 125
        arr1(2) = 150
        arr1(3) = 252
        arr1(4) = 253

Dim Find1 As String

Dim rng As Range

Set rng = arr1(5).Find()

If rng Is Nothing Then

    Debug.Print "Nope"

Else

    Debug.Print "Correct"

    End If

End Sub
```

Getting a run time 424 error.

Comment: Well you can't use `.Find` on an array. It's `Range.Find`...

Comment: Arrays (or their contents in this case, unless they happen to be Range's) don't have a `Find` method.  It's really unclear what you want to do here.

Comment: So instead of trying to use the array, I should just plant the values in a range of cells?

Comment: You can use a `Scripting.Dictionary` which has the property `.Exists` and can give you an array collection. [A guide here](http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html)